# win 10 home how to rename my home directory and account login

Tags: rename

I want to rename my win 10 account with my initials. When installed Win 10 created my account with my initials but appended to extra characters. This is different from my other accounts on my network and all other machines I use. I tried to rename my account but Win 10 did not rename my home folder. It changed my name but not my account or my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to rename my win 10 account with my initials. When installed Win 10 created my account with my initials but appended to extra characters.

What you describe indicates you have associated a local profile with a Microsoft Account.  Windows can create some really strange profile directories depending on the name of your Microsoft Account.  The following process will disassociate your Microsoft Account from your local account, prompt you for the name of the new profile name, which will allow you to easily rename your profile directory.

> 1. Open Settings, and click/tap on the Accounts icon.
> 2. Click/tap on Your info on the left side, click/tap on the Sign in with a local account instead link on the right side. (see screenshot
>    below)
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Click/tap on Next to confirm.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Enter credentials for your Microsoft account to verify.
> 5. Type in a user name, password, and password hint you want for your local account, and click/tap on Next.
>
> [image]
>
> 6. When ready to switch, click/tap on Sign out and finish.

The only limitation of this process is you will be unable to use a username that has been used in the past.  Once you have logged out of your profile, the profile directory will have renamed, allowing you to link your Microsoft Account to your local account.

Source: [How to Switch to a Local Account from a Microsoft Account in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5374-switch-local-account-windows-10-a.html)