# Windows 11, Filename of C:\Users\name was misspelt, renamed the file however when I open the command line It still shows the misspelt name

Tags: windows-11, user-profiles, filenames

When setting up my laptop I misspelt Artoid as Artoi, this meant the filename of the user file was Artoi, I changed the filename as shown in the photo below:

[The file is named Artoid in file explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmatK.png)

However when I open command prompt the directory shows the originally misspelt name as shown:

[The file is named Artoi in the command prompt file directory,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4jW7.png)

This is also true when copying the file directory from file explorer.

I have tried creating a new user and transferring all my files however cannot as it requires me to enter an email and I have already used my email for the original account, How do I change the name of the user file?

Comment: Associated, then Disassociated your account with a Microsoft Account, when prompted for the user profile name resolve the spelling error, then reassocoate the Microsoft Account with the profile

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1536543/win-10-home-how-to-rename-my-home-directory-and-account-login/1536554#1536554) is that process explained. How you do it on Windows 11 is virtually identical